# Django: Collect Static WinError 3

Tags: python, django

ive got a problem here. When i try to "collectstatic" from manage.py it just kicks me off with following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 3.1.3\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py",     line 23, in <module>
run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 182, in run_module
return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:/Users/mszalewski/PycharmProjects/OwnPixel_com\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in  execute
 self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242, in    run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 285, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 415, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 173, in handle_noargs
collected = self.collect()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 103, in collect
for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\finders.py", line 106, in list
for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\utils.py", line 25, in get_files
directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 250, in listdir
for entry in os.listdir(path):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden: 'C:\\Users\\mszalewski\\PycharmProjects\\static\\static'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The following is my settings.py:

```
import os
import os.path
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'OwnPixel_com.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'OwnPixel_com.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "templates").replace('\\','/')
)

if DEBUG:
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static-only").replace('\\', '/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media").replace('\\', '/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static").replace('\\', '/'),
)
```

At least my extendes urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                        document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                        document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Iam very sure that its the double backslash in the path (at the end of the error code).

I hope you can help me to fix my problem.

THANKS!!!

Regards, Marvyn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your Directory structure actually look like?

I doubt that 'C:\Users\mszalewski\PycharmProjects\static\static' is the folder you're intending to use for the Project specific static files.

My guess is that you want to change

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static").replace('\\', '/')
```

to

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "static")
```

Or something very similar.  And don't worry about the '\\' and '/'.  Python will actually get along just fine with some very odd combinations of them in the same path.

Comment: Wow great men, works fine!

Thank you very very much!

Whats the differnce between them both?

Comment: `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))` got the directory the __settings.py__ file was in by taking the `...\\DIR_NAME\\settings.py` down to just `...\\DIR_NAME`. When you called another `os.path.dirname` on `BASE_DIR`, you took it down another notch to `...\\ `

Answer (score 0):

Because you are in a virtual directory (assuming you've already activated the virtual env like so : `source <*Scripts* or *bin*>/activate`), the path that `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` expect are different.

---

1) `STATIC_ROOT` is expecting the location of the static files on your local machine (whether that be the cloud server you are serving these files on the computer that you are developing on) --> i.e. something like `STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/django_env_folder/mysite/static/mysite'`

2) `STATICFILES_DIRS` on the other hand is expecting the virtual_env path (remember, when you activate your virtual env using the command above, the paths that `os.<method>()` requires are different (do some debugging to see, try running `os.listdir('C:/....')` and you will notice different results than expected. SO try something like this for STATICFILES_DIRS --> `STATICFILES_DIRS = [ 
'mysite/static/mysite', 
]`

---

** This solution definitely works when serving on `localhost`, make sure `Debug = True` in your `settings.py`.